# Are there any good and free icons for web developers?

Tags: css, image, resources

I need some icons like github icons. just like favorite, settings, profile, remove, tag, etc, few colors, keep the icons small, it's a big problem for a coder to find these things.

[image: github icons]

this is github icons, it has a gray and white colors, to switch on hover and click

Comment: This should go on [graphicdesign.se].

Comment: The famfamfam Silk Icons -- http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/ -- are pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please search on icon finder http://www.iconfinder.com/ each one with it's name you will find what you want...